# Asp.net MVC and IIS 7 Remove Basic Authentication in web.config

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, iis-7

I published a site with a web hosting company and when someone hits the URL for the first time they are being prompted to log in using basic authentication. If you hit Cancel the site loads successfully and the user is not prompted again with the dialog box.

I contacted support and they are telling me (in a canned response) that it’s a programming issue.  Is there something in the web.config that I need to either add or remove to stop basic authentication from happening on the first request?

Site is built with  asp.net mvc 2, .net 4, and IIS 7. Thanks in advance for your help!

UPdate: I am using Forms based authentication on the site which is working once you click cancel on the Basic Authenciation dialog window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the answer my question. I had to connect to the web site using [IIS Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756935.aspx) and then disable Basic Authentication and enable anonymous.

Answer (score 1):

Look for the [authentication mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa291347%28VS.71%29.aspx) tag in the web.config (system.web node). Set the mode to "None".

So it will look something like this:

```
<authentication mode="None" />
```

Comment: I am using forms based authentication. Will this interfere?